# Asp.Net Framework - Multiple DLL's solution dockerfile for windows

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

We are building the .net framework application using jenkins and it creates a package which contains all the dll's for almost 30 solutions.

using this package we need to dockerize and write single dockerfile for all dll's for windows based.

so,if someone could show the steps to achieve the above use case?

I have to start writing dockerfile and test on my machine.

I am expecting to get the sample dockerfile and which .netframe base image should select

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far and what hasn't been working?

Comment: We have just started POC for dockerizing windows .netframework for 30 microservices and I just need an approach to start working on windows docker machine like creating dockerfile using existing dll's package and convert to an imagee which contains all the dll's.One more thing is when we start a container and how come all these dll's will start up and running?